# Kernel interaction with a custom filesystem driver

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, driver

I am trying to design a filesystem and write a driver for it under Linux. The source code is public and the URL for the source code is http://sourceforge.net/projects/pfspfs.

I found a strange problem, the Linux kernel will always call tmpfile / and lookup sni-qt_sogou-qimpanel_2162-u9AQ7h. I don't know why, many blocks and inode are allocated strangely.

Here are the steps I am using to mount the filesystem and generating some debug information with `pr_warn`:

1. mount -o loop -t pfs test.img /tmp
2. ls /tmp
3. touch /tmp/1
4. ls /tmp
5. touch /tmp/2
6. ls /tmp
7. touch /tmp/3

I use `pr_warn` to print some debug info. Here is the debug info:

```
     1. [  326.781181] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 0: 0
     2. [  334.253616] pfs: device loop0: pfs_lookup: lookup 1
     3. [  334.253625] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 0: 0
     4. [  334.253633] pfs: device loop0: pfs_create: create 1
     5. [  334.253636] pfs: device loop0: pfs_mknod: mknod 1
     6. [  334.253648] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 0: left 6
     7. [  334.253651] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 0: alloc 15, cnt = 5
     8. [  334.253656] pfs: device loop0: pfs_new_inode: alloc inode 15
     9. [  334.253660] pfs: device loop0: pfs_mknod: mknod 1: pfs_new_inode end
    10. [  334.253662] pfs: device loop0: pfs_add_nondir: add nondir 1
    11. [  334.253665] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 0: 0
    12. [  334.253669] pfs: device loop0: pfs_add_link: add link 1: left = 0, reclen = 24
    13. [  334.253671] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 1: 1
    14. [  334.253674] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
    15. [  334.253676] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
    16. [  334.253679] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 512
    17. [  334.253682] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 96, cnt = 511
    18. [  334.253856] pfs: device loop0: pfs_add_nondir: add nondir 1 end
    19. [  337.874792] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 0: 0
    20. [  337.874802] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 1: 0
    21. [  339.498179] pfs: device loop0: pfs_lookup: lookup sni-qt_sogou-qimpanel_2162-u9AQ7h
    22. [  339.498187] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 0: 0
    23. [  340.897097] pfs: device loop0: pfs_tmpfile: tmpfile /
    24. [  340.897114] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 0: left 5
    25. [  340.897118] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 0: alloc 14, cnt = 4
    26. [  340.897122] pfs: device loop0: pfs_new_inode: alloc inode 14
    27. [  340.897126] pfs: device loop0: pfs_tmpfile: tmpfile end
    28. [  340.897168] pfs: device loop0: pfs_tmpfile: tmpfile /
    29. [  340.897171] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 0: left 4
    30. [  340.897174] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 0: alloc 13, cnt = 3
    31. [  340.897176] pfs: device loop0: pfs_new_inode: alloc inode 13
    32. [  340.897179] pfs: device loop0: pfs_tmpfile: tmpfile end
    33. [  340.898339] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 0
    34. [  340.898342] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
    35. [  340.898345] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
    36. [  340.898347] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 511
    37. [  340.898350] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 104, cnt = 510
    38. [  340.926458] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 1
    39. [  340.926465] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
    40. [  340.926468] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
    41. [  340.926472] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 510
    42. [  340.926475] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 112, cnt = 509
    43. [  340.927868] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 2
    44. [  340.927871] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
    45. [  340.927874] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
    46. [  340.927876] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 509
    47. [  340.927879] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 120, cnt = 508
    48. [  340.928983] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 3
    49. [  340.928985] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
    50. [  340.928988] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
    51. [  340.928990] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 508
    52. [  340.928993] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 128, cnt = 507
    53. [  340.956804] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 4
    54. [  340.956809] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
    55. [  340.956811] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
    56. [  340.956814] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 507
    57. [  340.956816] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 136, cnt = 506
    58. [  340.957638] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 5
    59. [  340.957639] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
    60. [  340.957641] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
    61. [  340.957642] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 506
    62. [  340.957644] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 144, cnt = 505
    63. [  369.741734] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 0: 0
    64. [  369.741744] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 1: 0
    65. [  372.412704] pfs: device loop0: pfs_lookup: lookup 2
    66. [  372.412712] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 0: 0
    67. [  372.412720] pfs: device loop0: pfs_create: create 2
    68. [  372.412723] pfs: device loop0: pfs_mknod: mknod 2
    69. [  372.412727] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 0: left 3
    70. [  372.412730] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 0: alloc 12, cnt = 2
    71. [  372.412735] pfs: device loop0: pfs_new_inode: alloc inode 12
    72. [  372.412739] pfs: device loop0: pfs_mknod: mknod 2: pfs_new_inode end
    73. [  372.412742] pfs: device loop0: pfs_add_nondir: add nondir 2
    74. [  372.412745] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 0: 0
    75. [  372.412748] pfs: device loop0: pfs_add_link: add link 2: left = 4072, reclen = 24
    76. [  372.412751] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 1: 0
    77. [  372.412756] pfs: device loop0: pfs_add_nondir: add nondir 2 end
    78. [  375.500996] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 6
    79. [  375.501003] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
    80. [  375.501006] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
    81. [  375.501010] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 505
    82. [  375.501013] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 152, cnt = 504
    83. [  375.501054] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 0
    84. [  375.501056] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
    85. [  375.501058] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
    86. [  375.501061] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 511
    87. [  375.501063] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 152, cnt = 510
    88. [  375.536722] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 0
    89. [  375.536728] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
    90. [  375.536731] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
    91. [  375.536735] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 511
    92. [  375.536738] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 152, cnt = 510
    93. [  375.537954] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 1
    94. [  375.537958] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
    95. [  375.537960] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
    96. [  375.537963] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 510
    97. [  375.537965] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 144, cnt = 509
    98. [  375.539114] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 2
    99. [  375.539116] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc


100. [  375.539118] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
   101. [  375.539121] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 509
   102. [  375.539123] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 136, cnt = 508
   103. [  375.567196] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 3
   104. [  375.567202] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
   105. [  375.567205] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
   106. [  375.567209] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 508
   107. [  375.567212] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 128, cnt = 507
   108. [  375.568462] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 4
   109. [  375.568465] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
   110. [  375.568467] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
   111. [  375.568469] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 507
   112. [  375.568472] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 120, cnt = 506
   113. [  375.569630] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 5
   114. [  375.569633] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
   115. [  375.569635] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
   116. [  375.569638] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 506
   117. [  375.569640] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 112, cnt = 505
   118. [  375.596953] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block: get_block 6
   119. [  375.596957] pfs: device loop0: pfs_bmap_alloc: bmap_alloc
   120. [  375.596959] pfs: device loop0: pfs_atomic_alloc: pfs atomic alloc
   121. [  375.596961] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: left 505
   122. [  375.596963] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 1: alloc 104, cnt = 504
   123. [  386.356847] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 0: 0
   124. [  386.356854] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 1: 0
   125. [  389.444478] pfs: device loop0: pfs_lookup: lookup 3
   126. [  389.444487] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 0: 0
   127. [  389.444495] pfs: device loop0: pfs_create: create 3
   128. [  389.444498] pfs: device loop0: pfs_mknod: mknod 3
   129. [  389.444503] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 0: left 2
   130. [  389.444506] pfs: device loop0: pfs_alloc0: 0: alloc 11, cnt = 1
   131. [  389.444508] pfs: device loop0: pfs_new_inode: alloc inode 11
   132. [  389.444513] pfs: device loop0: pfs_mknod: mknod 3: pfs_new_inode end
   133. [  389.444515] pfs: device loop0: pfs_add_nondir: add nondir 3
   134. [  389.444518] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 0: 0
   135. [  389.444521] pfs: device loop0: pfs_add_link: add link 3: left = 4048, reclen = 24
   136. [  389.444524] pfs: device loop0: pfs_get_block_number: get block numberof 1: 0
   137. [  389.444529] pfs: device loop0: pfs_add_nondir: add nondir 3 end
```

Comment: You need to post code here that replicates the problem.

Comment: Try mounting at some mount point other than `/tmp`. In an active system, there will be lots of spurious activity in `/tmp`.

Comment: the source code is large, i have provide the link of project. the problem is the kernel will always to call tmpfile /, i don't know why.

Comment: thank you for your help Rob, but when i mounting a pfs filesystem on /tmp, it will fall into drop-dead loop and cannot umount. do you know why, brother